# Como extrair dados desse tipo de array? É uma consulta no WordPress

Tags: php, array, wordpress

Preciso extrair o `e-mail` e o `nome` deste **usuário** mas não sei como proceder neste formato de `arrays`. Podem me ajudar a aprender como proceder para extrair estes dados e gravá-los em uma variável?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é só dar `variavel = foo[25].meta_value`?

Comment: @DarkHyudrA teria como não usar este **[25]**?

Comment: É um array de objetos, pode usar um foreach ou diretamente pode acessar um, `$arr[25]->meta_value`

Comment: Ia ser tão legal se você fizesse um search aqui mesmo no SOpt antes de perguntar... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22stdclass+object%22